# Does fhir has a resource to represent a workflow task?

Tags: hl7-fhir

We are trying to integrate fhir in our product.

To utilize fhir as much as possible, we want also use fhir api to retrieve our workflow tasks.

I checked the fhir resource list, seems cannot find one.

Could somebody help to point out which resource suitable for this scenario?
or do you have better suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: please explain in detail the kind of things that you mean by "a workflow task"

Comment: Hi, Grahame
Let me give an basic example, after CT, physician will receive a patient's image, then in our system, we will start a reading task for this physician.
then for this physician, he/she might have several reading tasks at the same time. 
what we want to do is to query the task list based on this physician.
hope this make it clear.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

airhork, sounds like you want to build an application protocol that incorporates FHIR resources and resources unique to your scenario for the tasks in your workflow. A reading task might be something you could define by extending the FHIR "Other" resource. A physician would pull down the list of reading tasks and this might include hypermedia (see http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) that would provide links to actions a user could take given the current state of the reading task resource. For example, it might include a link to a "readComplete" action resource that a user of your system could use to indicate the task has been read. Once it has been read it would no longer appear in the reading list. Or there might be other state transitions that are possible - it's really up to you as the designer of the application protocol.

FHIR doesn't prescribe the use of hypermedia for particular resources. But you can certainly add this to your implementation so consumers of your API that can understand something like HAL can use them.

Here's a link to the complete list of resources under consideration for DSTU2: http://hl7.org/implement/standards/FHIR-Develop/resourcelist.html

I'd also recommend looking at how FHIR currently defines Operations and the OperationDefinition resource.

http://hl7.org/implement/standards/FHIR-Develop/operations.html
http://hl7.org/implement/standards/FHIR-Develop/operationdefinition.html

Comment: I would use a List resource for tracking the todo list

Answer (score 0):

If from a workflow perspective, you mean keeping a record of "please do" and "has been done", that sounds like Order/OrderResponse to me.  However, those resources (specifically the Order resource) isn't currently set up to do what you want because it doesn't have a mechanism to convey *what* you want to do with the target resource.  (In your example "please read").  I can foresee a lot of other workflow-like requests - "please fulfill" is the presumed default, but there could be more specific variants ("please administer" vs. "please dispense", "please collect sample" vs. "please perform test", etc.).  There can also be things like "please suspend", "please cancel", "please renew".

I *think* it is reasonable to tackle all of these things using Order/OrderResponse, but it can't right now and the pair haven't received a lot of focus in terms of connectathons/implementation just yet.  My recommendation would be to look at them and see if they feel right to you, and if so, submit a change request to add a "code" element.  (And in the meantime, you can introduce your own as a modifierExtension if you can't wait for the DSTU 2 release in summer 2015.)